# How do I access response content in WSGI middleware for Flask?

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

I want to write middleware for Flask that changes the data in an HTML response. In Django, I could use a `Middleware` class and access `response.content` to change the content. How can I access and modify the response content in Flask or WSGI middleware?

```py
class Middleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response=None):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        self.process_response(request, response)
        return response

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        html = response.content.decode('utf-8')
        # do stuff with the HTML
        return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest equivalent of Django's "middleware" in Flask is Flask's `before_request` and `after_request` functions. They can introspect and modify the request and response at the same layer as the Flask app.

To get the response content, access `response.get_data(as_text=True)` in an `after_request` function. The function must return a response, either modify `response.data` directly or create a new response with `app.make_response(new_data)`. You can also modify any other properties of the resonse.

```py
from flask import request

@app.before_request
def modify_incoming():
    if {some test on request}:
        ...

    # can return app.make_response() to end the request early

@app.after_request
def modify_outgoing(response):
    html = response.get_data(as_text=True)
    response.data = {modify html}
    return response
```

---

WSGI middleware (which can be used with any WSGI framework, including Django) is at a layer outside the app itself, so you would need to either use the basic interface provided by the WSGI spec. Werkzeug's utilities may be useful at this lower layer.

```py
class ModifyHTMLMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        # can modify environ to affect what the wrapped application sees
        app_iter = self.app(environ, start_response)
        # decode and encode need to use the appropriate codec
        html = b"".join(app_iter).decode("utf8")
        # modify html
        return [html.encode("utf8")]
```